# CSS3 rotate animation not working (jsFiddle)

Tags: animation, css

I am trying to get a `<div>` element to rotate constantly on the spot using CSS3. I have a jsFiddle all set up with the HTML and CSS3 but it's not doing a thing. Any help?

http://jsfiddle.net/8FUK8/

Please note I am testing in Chrome and therefore only using the `-webkit-` prefix at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do the same thing for keyframe change `@keyframes` to `@-webkit-keyframes`

Answer (score 1):

I answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582612/rotating-360deg-text-marquee-animation-inside-a-circle-div/9582861) recently. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HS68a/3/) for your convenience. You can fine-tune the styles to fit your needs, but the rotation styles will be left intact.

Answer (score 0):

You should use animation and @keyframes compatibility selectors. for example

```
-moz-animation:1s foo infinite alternate;
-ms-animation:1s foo infinite alternate;
-webkit-animation:1s foo infinite alternate;

@-moz-keyframes foo {}

@-ms-keyframes foo {}

@-webkit-keyframes foo {}
```